# Not understanding current direction for this specific circuit (very basic question)

Tags: power, capacitor, circuit-analysis, circuit-design, power-electronics

For the following circuit, I am for some reason just having troubles with understanding why the current (circled blue) moves in the up direction across the capacitor.

[image]

Or for example, this following circuit why it also moves up across the capacitor.

[image]

Why does the current just not flow down?
What causes these capacitors to discharge?

Essentially what causes one capacitor to discharge while the other one charges?

Updated:

What is the case where a capacitor is in series with a capacitor and resistor in parallel, that the top capacitor will always charge, but the bottom capacitor will charge and then discharge back through the resistor:

[image]

Comment: Edit the lines to show the voltages

Comment: Perhaps it doesn't. When you've done the analysis, if it turns out to be negative then it means that it flows in the opposite direction to that assumed. In more complicated circuits it's often impossible to predict current flow directions with any accuracy. So just assume directions; make sure they comply with KCL; and let the analysis take care of the actual directions.

Comment: Have you tried simulation and current speed feature in falstad?